# Аналог динамических параметров Директа в Google Adwords

Tags: google-adwords

Есть ли аналог [Динамических параметов Директа](https://yandex.ru/support/direct/statistics/url-tags.xml?lang=ru#dynamic) в Google adwords?

Answer (score 0):

Аналог называется [ValueTrack](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305529?hl=ru). Еще одна статья по использованию [Использование динамических URL отслеживания](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2549100?hl=ru).